# A web browser within a web browser

Tags: php, javascript, html, iframe, proxy

Is it possible to have a web browser within a web browser?

For example: I want to have a search bar that I can type a url in, on my website which can load a webpage inside the current page I am on. (I know, Inception) but is this possible?

Could you use an iframe or some?

Comment: Yes, an iframe will work. Why don't you try it?

Comment: an iframe would be a webpage within a webpage. you could probably embed ie-in-ie using an activex control, but an iframe is probably enough for what you want.

Comment: Could you show me some sample code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will have to code the address bar and go, back, forward, refresh with jquery.. once you have those functions, yes, use the iFrame and load the content accordingly via jquery.

Comment: I think it can be confusing to the user to have two back buttons/address bars etc. Some websites also don't allow framing.

Comment: Could you show me a working example on jsFiddle? I don't need the back forward ect buttons just an input

Comment: check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2s46A/8/) it has a working in browser browser thing. only address bar and go button for concept. try to navigate to sites like: reddit, newgrounds, imgur, etc. (dont forget to include 'http://'. i did not code in a conditional to check for address) @pimvdb - you are correct about the frame restriction on many websites (google, yahoo, msn, stackoverflow, youtube, etc). as for the confusion, if done correctly it could actually be a beneficial element depending on what he is intending to use it for.

Comment: McMastermind THANK YOu THANK YOU THANK YOU